# Identification space

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

Identifying in $\mathbb{S}^{n-1} \times [0,1]$ the set $\mathbb{S}^{n-1} \times \{ 0\}$ to a point and the set $\mathbb{S}^{n-1} \times \{ 1\}$ with another point. The result is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^{n}$.

I don't know how to start because I don't know the result of the identification

Comment: You take an open cylinder, seal up the bottom, then seal up the top. That's what it says.